# calculating mean and standard deviation of SRTM in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I intend to calculate and export mean and standard deviation of SRTM 90-ARC for multiple points saved in a csv file (called 2_1) using GGE. But, when I run this code and press 'run' in task bar to save new csv file, I encounter an error ('FeatureCollection (Error) Error in map(ID=00000000000000000000): GeometryConstructors.Point: Inputs must be Number, List, or Geometry. Found type 'List''). I attached the link of the code. can anyone help me to fix it? thanks in advance. https://code.earthengine.google.com/18f4249c654f8f4027445f00a443931b

Here is the link of the code I wrote :
https://code.earthengine.google.com/18f4249c654f8f4027445f00a443931b

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text.  The link is asking me to sign in.